# Can I use/trust an id_token to both validate a request and extract the user's information on the server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm using node.js, lambda, cognito. An authenticated client sends tokens in the header to authenticate requests. The lambda function is verifying the JWT signature using the `jsonwebtoken` package.

I am trying to avoid making an external call on the server for each request to get the user's identity from their `access_token`, and I can see the `id_token` contains the information I require.

However, I read that using the `id_token` for request validation is not good.

If I call `jwt.verify()` on an `id_token`, am I right in thinking that:

1) It checks the `id_token` has not been tampered with by checking it against the signature?

2) The server can trust the `id_token`'s payload once verified?

3) The `id_token` expires at the same time the `access_token` does?

If that's the case, then why not use the `id_token` in place of the `access_token` for requests with the server?

Or should I send both and check both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes

You can use the `id_token` to validate requests. The Cognito docs say "The ID token can also be used to authenticate users against your resource servers or server applications"

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)

Technically the `id_token` is for verifying identity and the `access_token` is for verifying access, but you can use the `id_token` for both if you wanted.